# How to make Django link jumping game with a web browser inside the app?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to build a django application which is an online link jumping game similar to the [WikiGame](http://thewikigame.com/speed-race) but not specific to the Wikipedia site. It is a game in which you visit a website and the user jumps around links on one website and tries to make it to another target webpage while player stats such as the webpages jumped/number of clicks is updated on a status bar as the game is played. 
In order to implement this game, the django app needs to be running along side a normal web browser process similar to WikiGame. This could be analogous to implementing UIWebView if this was a mobile app in ObjC. Does Django have any packages that do similar things?

Ideally, I'd like an app which when visiting myapp.com will start a browser inside that window and take the user to google.com for example and the url will be myapp.com/http://google.com/ (perahps the slashes would be decoded out) My url.py looks like this which should allow me to pass any website URL into it and then pass this argument into whatever django webview approaches you guys can suggest to me. Thanks for any input. Basically right now, I just want to get something working where if I enter into the URL: myapp.com/http://www.google.com it should show google inside my application tab. What is the best way to approach that?

```
 url(r'^(?P<url_param>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-%/]*)/$', views.webview, name='anywebsiteinapp')
```

Comment: Hey guys, I'm sorry if people don't like the question. Please let me know why the downvotes. I am just trying to get a very basic idea of how to display a website that has the address passed into the URL of the app URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need to use `iframe` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) in your template like follows:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom"></iframe>
```

Second thing you need to do is to pass your parameter from your view into your template:

```
def webview(request, url_param):
    context = { "my_url": url_param }
    return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', context)
```

Then display it in `mytemplate.html`

```
<iframe src="{{ my_url }}"></iframe>
```

Some sites do not allow you to show their contents via `iframe` though. `http://www.google.com` is one of them. It has `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` HTTP-header which prevents page of being embedded into another sites.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of iframe actually but only posted about another way because like you said, many websites prevent being embedded, but I guess this is the only way possible. Do you know any way to fix that most sites don't work through embedding like youtube and google?

Comment: @SwAvGuy, I think this is hardly possible. Anyway, you can embed both Google and YouTube if modify links: add `/custom` to `google.com` to embed Google search page and change YouTube link like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6cxZp4ii6c` to `http://www.youtube.com/embed/j6cxZp4ii6c`. Last link can be embedded.